# SwiftUI: How to align view to HStack's subview?

Tags: view, swiftui, ios13

I want to align the circle to the TileView "1"'s center  at top left. Is there any other like centre constraint of UIView?

[image]

```
struct BoardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    TileView(number: 1)
                    TileView(number: 2)
                }
                HStack {
                    TileView(number: 3)
                    TileView(number: 4)
                }
            }
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.8))

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach using custom alignment guides

[image: SwiftUI center dependent shapes]

```
extension VerticalAlignment {
   private enum VCenterAlignment: AlignmentID {
      static func defaultValue(in dimensions: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
         return dimensions[VerticalAlignment.center]
      }
   }
   static let vCenterred = VerticalAlignment(VCenterAlignment.self)
}

extension HorizontalAlignment {
   private enum HCenterAlignment: AlignmentID {
      static func defaultValue(in dimensions: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
         return dimensions[HorizontalAlignment.center]
      }
   }
   static let hCenterred = HorizontalAlignment(HCenterAlignment.self)
}

struct BoardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .hCenterred, vertical: .vCenterred)) {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    TileView(number: 1)
                        .alignmentGuide(.vCenterred) { $0[VerticalAlignment.center] }
                        .alignmentGuide(.hCenterred) { $0[HorizontalAlignment.center] }
                    TileView(number: 2)
                }
                HStack {
                    TileView(number: 3)
                    TileView(number: 4)
                }
            }
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.8))
                .alignmentGuide(.vCenterred) { $0[VerticalAlignment.center] }
                .alignmentGuide(.hCenterred) { $0[HorizontalAlignment.center] }

        }
    }
}
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestBoardAlignments.swift)

Answer (score 0):

Using **GeometryReader** and **preference**

[image: portrait mode]

[image: landscape mode]

**GeometryReader** - let us to get geometryProxy of a view ( according to the parent view / space provide by parent )

*Note:- child view stays at their own (parent cant force them position or size)*

**.preference(key:,value:)** - this modifier let us get some values( geometryProxy ) out of the view. so that we can access child's geometry proxy from parent as well.

*comment below for any question about these topics.*

here is the code,
(plus point - you can animate your circle's position easily.(by adding **.animation()** modifier. Ex- if you want your circle move when user touch on a title)

***complete code***

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var centerCoordinateOfRectangele: MyPreferenceData = MyPreferenceData(x: 0, y: 0)
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    GeometryReader { (geometry)  in
                        TileView(number: 1)
                            .preference(key: MyPreferenceKey.self, value: MyPreferenceData(x: geometry.frame(in: .named("spaceIWantToMoveMyView")).midX, y:  geometry.frame(in: .named("spaceIWantToMoveMyView")).midY))

                    }
                    TileView(number: 2)
                }.onPreferenceChange(MyPreferenceKey.self) { (value) in
                        self.centerCoordinateOfRectangele = value
                }
                HStack {
                    TileView(number: 3)
                    TileView(number: 4)
                }
            }
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.8))
                .position(x: centerCoordinateOfRectangele.x, y: centerCoordinateOfRectangele.y)

        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "spaceIWantToMoveMyView") //to get values relative to this layout
                                                        // watch where i have use this name


    }
}

struct TileView: View{
    let number: Int

    var body: some View{
        GeometryReader { (geometry) in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
        }
    }
}

struct MyPreferenceData:Equatable {
    let x: CGFloat
    let y: CGFloat
}

struct MyPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {

    typealias Value = MyPreferenceData

    static var defaultValue: MyPreferenceData = MyPreferenceData(x: 0, y: 0)

    static func reduce(value: inout MyPreferenceData, nextValue: () -> MyPreferenceData) {
        value = nextValue()
    }   
}
```

---

**Code explanation ->**

data model which I want to grab from the child view

```
struct MyPreferenceData:Equatable {
    let x: CGFloat
    let y: CGFloat
}
```

Key

```
struct MyPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {

    typealias Value = MyPreferenceData

    static var defaultValue: MyPreferenceData = MyPreferenceData(x: 0, y: 0)

    static func reduce(value: inout MyPreferenceData, nextValue: () -> MyPreferenceData) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

defaultValue - SwiftUI use this, when there are no explicit value set
reduce() - getCalled when SwiftUI want to give values (we can use `.preference()` modifier on many views with the same key)

we add the `.preference()` modifier which we want to get values